# Rails how can I pass multiple values through check_box_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass multiple values to a custom function that I created through the check_box_tag, however I don't really know how to do it, I have check online for hours but didn't help.

Basically I have a details view, and I try to pass the date and id information of the detail to the controller and call the create method.

```
<%= form_tag( { :action => 'create' } ) do %>
    <%  @details.each do |detail| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'date[]', detail.date, false, :id => detail.id %>

        <%= detail.date %> 
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Register!' %>
<% end %>
```

I try to set the custom value but when I type params in the debugger this is what it shows

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3PKBBKNmXyAfdSllTWBFP8EafhbrJ8rCgOeOp2NbeBA=", "date"=>["2013-06-08"], "commit"=>"Register!", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"}

I really don't know how should I do it.

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: Why is passing just the id not enough?

Comment: You can send the ids to ur controller through these checkboxes and collect the specific dates from details .

Answer (score 8):

please using array dates.

```
<%= form_tag( { :action => 'create' } ) do %>
    <%  @details.each do |detail| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'detail[dates][]', detail.date, false, :id => detail.id %>
        <%= detail.date %> 
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Register!' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried but it still doesn't work. Am I arranging the arguments in a right way?This is what I got form params: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3PKBBKNmXyAfdSllTWBFP8EafhbrJ8rCgOeOp2NbeBA=", "date"=>{"dates"=>["2013-06-08"]}, "commit"=>"Register!", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_items"}