# has_many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making an online fashion store. I have a Category Model and a Sizes Model. A model can have many sizes. A Size can have many Categories.

Therefore i am using has_many through association. The category model and sizes model will be linked via a table called category_sizes.

I will create a bunch of sizes like XS, Small, Medium. Then I will create a category Lets say Shirt then i can select all the Sizes a Shirt will have. Then click create.

How do i make the sizes appear in my view? I tried for hours.

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :items
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  has_many :category_sizes
  has_many :sizes, through: :category_sizes
end
```

Sizes Model

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
  has_many :category_sizes
  has_many :categories, through: :category_sizes
end
```

category_size model

```
class CategorySize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :sizes
end
```

Here is my form.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
              <div class="form-inputs">
                <%= f.input :name %>
                <%= f.association :category_sizes %>
                <%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Parrent ID If Applicable"},include_blank: true %>
                <div class="form-actions"><%= f.button :submit %></div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150915113019) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "categories", ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry"

  create_table "category_sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "size_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "category_sizes", ["category_id"], name: "index_category_sizes_on_category_id"
  add_index "category_sizes", ["size_id"], name: "index_category_sizes_on_size_id"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "items", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_items_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "items", ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id"

  create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",               default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",           default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.string   ">"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
<%= f.select(:size_id, Size.all.map {|s| [s.title, s.id]}) %>
```

Comment: This worked <%= f.select(:category_sizes, Size.all.map {|s| [s.title, s.id]}) %>. However do you know how to change it so i can choose many sizes? I can only choose 1 at the moment?

Comment: You will need a check_box_tag I think. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939931/rails-how-can-i-pass-multiple-values-through-check-box-tag

Answer (score 0):

In your controller define ,

```
@size_variant_array = @category.sizes
```

In your view,

```
<%= select_tag 'size',options_for_select(@size_variant_array.collect{ |pv| [pv.title, pv.id] }) ,:prompt => "Please Select"%>
```